# AWS Free account renewal or closing after an year of free subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services

Just have a question around, AWS Free tier accoount, Will they be charging after one year?
Should I be closing it after an year?
The account that I am using is for my perssonal practice.

Comment: I found that they start charging before a year. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528559/aws-how-to-disable-all-services

Comment: An account does not cost anything, the services cost something. And they will certainly charging for services usage that exceeds the free tier, both if you exceed the 1-year-limit and the free-forever-limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "AWS Free Account".

Rather, for the first 12 months of a new AWS Account, the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) provides some billing discounts that provide certain amounts of service at no charge, such as 5GB of Amazon S3 storage and an Amazon EC2 micro instance for Windows and Linux.

If you have been using services that fall under the Free Tier, then after 12 months you would start being charged normal prices for those services. You can look in your Billing Console to view historical usage information.

There are actually some services that provide a free tier *every* month, even after 12 months. Consult the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) page for details.