# Does my bill become 0$ if I delete every resource before the end of a month on AWS (Amazon Cloud)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-billing

I'm a student and I'm new to AWS. I've already created a Free Tier account and set my budget to 1$. I only use the account for testing/learning purposes. After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528559/aws-how-to-disable-all-services) on SOF (about a guy who creates an account for learning purposes like me, then loses a bunch of $ for no reason), I'm quite worried. I have some questions about **how Amazon charges me**.

Does my bill become **0$** if I **terminate every service/remove all resources** before the **end of a month**? I sent this question to AWS support and they said as long as I stop every **Outbound Data transfer service** then it's fine. People on the internet also said that if I **remove all the resources** after testing/learning then it's ok too.

I'm still not sure. Does it mean that I can use every service as much as possible, as long as I terminate/remove everything before the end of a month then I won't get charged? And at the start of the next month, I can do everything again? Sound like an exploit and impossible case to me.

It's like at the start of a month, you borrow an iPhone 13 from an Apple shop, you use the phone for free for 1 month, and at the end of a month, you factory reset the phone and brought it back to the shop. Next month you do everything again.

Comment: If you haven't already, enable billing alerts and see [Creating a billing alarm to monitor your estimated AWS charges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html).

Comment: @jarmod I created Budget (1$ ~ Free Tier Budget) and Billing Alert. But as far as I know, it's only alarming by email, not forcing stop all the service. 1$ is very small so I don't think there is anything I can do if they suddenly charged me. When I receive the alert I'd have already lost some $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're misunderstanding something. AWS costs accrue as you use services. For example, if you start an EC2 instance, use it for 10 minutes, then stop it, you will be billed for each minute of usage at the rate shown on the EC2 pricing page. Similarly, if you store objects on S3 for a period of time and later delete them, you will be billed for the duration you stored the object.

You can see what services are available for free perpetually on the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all).

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I know that I can't 100% trust AWS customer support.

Comment: May I ask, in the free tier services list, the Amazon S3 is free for 12 months with 5 GB storage available, 20000 get, and 2000 pull requests. Does it mean that as long as I store less than 5gb and perform less than 20000/2000 get/pull requests I will be fine? Or as you say I will be charged as long as I have data on S3 bucket?

Comment: Happy to help. If this answered the question, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as long as you stay within the listed constraints you will not be charged.

Comment: That's 2000 put requests, not 2000 pull requests.